# Beautiful Soup find element with multiple classes

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
<div data-list="1" data-href="/a/ajaxPhones?id=46420863" class="action-link 
showPhonesLink">Показать телефон</div>
```

How do I find the above element in Beautiful Soup?

I've tried the following, but it didn't work:

```
show = soup.find('div', {'class': 'action-link showPhonesLink'})
```

How can I get that element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing the soup in show = soup.find() is

```
source = requests.get(URL to get).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')
```

try:

```
show = soup.find('div', class_='action-link showPhonesLink').text
```

.text doesn't always work, but I've found the result doesn't really change without it.

i could give a more help answer if you could provide a little more details.

Answer (score 4):

Use a selector:

```
show = soup.select_one('div.action-link.showPhonesLink')
```

Or match the exact `class` attribute:

```
show = soup.find('div', class_='action-link showPhonesLink')

# or (for older versions of BeautifulSoup)
show = soup.find('div', attr={'class': 'action-link showPhonesLink'})
```

Note that with the second method the order of the classes is important, as well as the whitespace, since it is an exact match on the `class` attribute. **If anything changes in the `class` attribute (e.g. one more space between the classes) it will not match**.

I would suggest the first method.