# Get data from HTML page

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have some data from a HTML page as follows

```
<span class="some class abc-vc"> 123</span>
<span class="some class vde-bc"> 435</span>
<span class="some class v9mo-04mg"> 456 </span>
```

I would only like to search for

```
some class
```

part of the tag so that I can store the variables one by one

How can I achieve this?

code:

```
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
import bs4 
url = 'url'
page = urlopen(url).read()
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
data = soup.find('span',{'class':'some class'})
print (data.text)
```

Comment: `soup.find('span', class_='some class')`

Comment: Like mentioned here?: https://stackoverflow.com/q/52816683/4636715

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regular expression to find specific items.Try below code.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

data='''<span class="some class abc-vc"> 123</span>
<span class="some class vde-bc"> 435</span>
<span class="some class v9mo-04mg"> 456 </span>'''
soup=BeautifulSoup(data,'html.parser')

for item in soup.find_all('span',class_=re.compile('some class')):
    print(item.text)
```

Output:

```
123
435
456
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. A regular expression is actually what I was looking for, but it turns out I was looking for the wrong tag. The correct data that I need is:

<span style="font-size:90%"><b>100</b></span>

Would you know how to get this?

Comment: @user3702643 : so you need the value of 100 from this tag right?

Comment: Yes correct. Each row has the exact same tag as follows

<span style="font-size:90%"><b>100</b></span>
<span style="font-size:90%"><b>200</b></span>
<span style="font-size:90%"><b>300</b></span>

Comment: you don't need regular expression for that.You can find like that way ```for item in soup.find_all('span'):
    print(item.find('b').text)```

Comment: I am not sure though how the structure  of your html

Comment: There are other span tags with data that I do not need. The only data that I need is the data that contains the tag <span style="font-size:90%">

Comment: ```for item in soup.find_all('span',style=re.compile('font-size:90%')):
    print(item.find('b').text)``` This should work

Answer (score 1):

In HTML, distinct classes are separated by spaces. So that bottom span for example has three classes: `some`, `class`, and `v9mo-04mg`.

To find all tags that contain the class `some` and the class `class`, use a list as your dictionary value:

```
data = soup.find('span', {'class':['some', 'class']})
```

If you need multiple, then replace the `.find()` method with `.find_all()`.

Comment: I am still unable to get the required data. I get AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Comment: @user3702643 That means the find was invalid. I tested this with the HTML you posted in your question and it worked fine. Perhaps `print(soup)` just to make sure it's all working fine

Comment: You were right. Upon closer inspection of the soup, I realized that the data I needed was actually in the tag below. Any help for this?

<span style="font-size:90%"><b>100</b>

Answer (score 0):

They are compound classes. You can join them with "." and pass to select

```
elements = [item for item in soup.select('.some.class')]
```