# How to read table with double class in html using beautiful soup

Tags: html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

How to read a table in an HTML page where the table content has two classes associated with. Here is the sample table html code:

```html
<table class="table table-tab">

<thead>
<tr>
<th>Col1_Heading</th>
<th>Col2_Heading</th>
</tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
<tr><td>123</td><td>456</td></tr>
</tbody></table>
```

I'm trying it as:

```
table = soup.find('table', attrs={'class':['table','table-tab']})
```

Comment: would the solutions in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52816683/beautiful-soup-find-element-with-multiple-classes) post work?

Comment: Thanks for sharing, it helped me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using

```
soup.find('table', class_='table table-tab')
```

or, using css selectors

```
soup.select('table[class="table table-tab"]')
```

Comment: Thank you, for the response. It actually helped me.