# beautifulsoup problems extracting a table

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

It's literally my first time using `BeautifulSoup`, and I'm having trouble extracting the table I want to work with ([https://ansm.sante.fr/disponibilites-des-produits-de-sante/medicaments]). I want to extract the table `table table-products sortable searchable`  .

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url="https://ansm.sante.fr/disponibilites-des-produits-de-sante/medicaments"
html_content = requests.get(url).text

soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, "html.parser")

table = soup.find("table", class_="table table-products sortable searchable ")
table_data = table.tbody.find_all("tr")
```

This outputs:
`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'tbody'`.

I guess I'm not reaching the table correctly, which is why it comes out as `'NoneType'`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [BeautifulSoup and class with spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46718366/beautifulsoup-and-class-with-spaces)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There must be something wrong with the CSS class filter, **without it works**:

```
table = soup.find("table")
table_data = table.tbody.find_all("tr")
```

Add the class filter back but **remove the trailing space**:

```
table = soup.find("table", class_="table table-products sortable searchable")  # last space at the end removed
```

Works too.

See:

- [BeautifulSoup and class with spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46718366/beautifulsoup-and-class-with-spaces)
- [Beautiful Soup find element with multiple classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52816683/beautiful-soup-find-element-with-multiple-classes).

Answer (score 2):

you have an extra space at the end class - `table = soup.find("table", class_="table table-products sortable searchable ")` But you can get table more simple:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_html('https://ansm.sante.fr/disponibilites-des-produits-de-sante/medicaments')[1]
print(df)
```

OUTPUT:

```
                          Statut  ... Remise à disposition
0               Rupture de stock  ...                  NaN
1               Rupture de stock  ...                  NaN
2               Rupture de stock  ...                  NaN
3    Tension d'approvisionnement  ...                  NaN
4           Remise à disposition  ...                  NaN
..                           ...  ...                  ...
373   Arrêt de commercialisation  ...                  NaN
374             Rupture de stock  ...                  NaN
375             Rupture de stock  ...                  NaN
376         Remise à disposition  ...          2 mars 2021
377             Rupture de stock  ...                  NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two tables in the webpage and class value `table table-products sortable searchable` select both of them. The desired table is 2 and I use pandas to pull the complete table data

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_html('https://ansm.sante.fr/disponibilites-des-produits-de-sante/medicaments')[1]
print(df)
```

**Output**:

```
    Statut  ... Remise à disposition
0               Rupture de stock  ...                  NaN
1               Rupture de stock  ...                  NaN
2               Rupture de stock  ...                  NaN
3    Tension d'approvisionnement  ...                  NaN
4           Remise à disposition  ...                  NaN
..                           ...  ...                  ...
373   Arrêt de commercialisation  ...                  NaN
374             Rupture de stock  ...                  NaN
375             Rupture de stock  ...                  NaN
376         Remise à disposition  ...          2 mars 2021
377             Rupture de stock  ...                  NaN

[378 rows x 4 columns]
```