# Beautiful Soup including a button which has same class name but has an additional class name in the tag

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to scrape data from william hill to get horse racing odds using a combination of selenium to click to different pages and beautiful soup to pull the data I need. The issue I'm having is in the below section of my code in the odds variable, you can see I want to return the information from a button on the page, I do this using the class name of "sp-betbutton", then I get the text from the span element in that tag using the next two lines of code - this outputs the odds of the horse e.g. 7/1

```
 hncount = 0
 hdswitch = True
 bbcount = 0
 while hdswitch:
   try:
       horse_number = soup.find_all("div",{"class" : "horse-number"})[hncount]
       horse_name = soup.find_all("span",{"class" : "selection__title"})[hncount]
       odds = soup.find_all("div",{"class" : "sp-betbutton"})[bbcount]
       horse_odds = odds.find_all("span")[0]
       horseodds = horse_odds.text
       hncount += 1
       bbcount += 2
    except:
       hdswitch = False
```

On some races on the site, a race will offer bigger odds on a particular horse and put this at the top of the page above the rest of the horses, the issue is this bet button includes the same class name as my odds variable (see below), only it has another class name in the tag too. The issue is that when I run my code on the page, it grabs this first class name, then puts everything else out of alignment with the names and horse number that it also pulls.

```
<button class="sp-betbutton sp-betbutton--enhanced has-icon">
```

Is there a way to specifically say I want to only find data that have the exact class name in the tag "sp-betbutton" - and not include ones that have the additional class names?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Beautiful Soup find element with multiple classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52816683/beautiful-soup-find-element-with-multiple-classes)

Answer (score 0):

First, the sample button in your question is invalid - [both start and end tags are required.](https://www.w3resource.com/html/button/HTML-button-tag-and-element.php)

If you fix that and use css selectors, you can find elements which have only the exact tag name.

For example, if your html looks like this:

```
<html>
  <button class="sp-betbutton sp-betbutton--enhanced has-icon"/>
  <button class="sp-betbutton has-icon"/>
  <button class="sp-betbutton"/>
  <button class="sp-betbutton sp-betbutton--enhanced"/>
</html>
```

then

```
soup.select('button[class="sp-betbutton"]')
```

should return only

```
<button class="sp-betbutton"></button>
```